# Using a Loop and the Data Frame Style property in Python to Highlight Excel Column Cells

Tags: python, css, loops, dataframe, automation

I'm trying to automate a simple process. What I want the code to do is to go through every article in 'Article URL' and check if the company listed under 'Sub-Category Name' is present in that article. If so, I want it to highlight the cell green, and if not, red. I managed to make it work on one cell (See Image 1).

But then I tried to loop it through the entire spreadsheet. And for the life of me, I can't figure out why it's not working (See code below). The loop runs without any errors, but when I go to the document, it is not highlighted at all (See Image 2).

I suspect it has something to do with the change to the spreadsheet not being saved after each loop. But how do you save a spreadsheet to a variable because the style application can only be viewed once the data frame is exported and saved as an xlsx.

Thank you for your assistance in advance :)

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVONN.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuVhL.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as rq 

path='/Users/mbongeni/Documents/Career/Internship/ProjectRunway/ProjectRunwayCopy.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(path)

#select following columns from df:
dfR = df[['Category Name','Sub-Category Name','Country','Article URL']]

#filter by online news coverage in column Category Name
is_online = dfR['Category Name']=='Online News Coverage: Project Runway SA'
dfR_online = dfR[is_online]

#colour functions
def cell_color_g(d):
    return 'background-color: green'
def cell_color_r(d):
     return 'background-color: red'

#test loop on first five rows:
for i, site in enumerate(dfR_online[0:4]['Article URL']):  

     #download site and check if strings in 'condition' are on site
     site_download = rq.get(site)
     condition = "Project Runway" in site_download.text \
                 and "South Africa" in site_download.text \
                 or "Project Runway SA" in site_download.text 

     if condition:
        #color cell row i in column 'Article URL' green
        dfR_online.style.\
        applymap(cell_color_g, subset=pd.IndexSlice[i,['Article URL']])

     else:
         #color cell row i in column 'Article URL' red
         dfR_online.style.\
         applymap(cell_color_r, subset=pd.IndexSlice[i, ['Article URL']])

#recreate spreadsheet with style applied for specified range 

dfR_online.style.to_excel('HighlightedSheet.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: Please post your code instead of a screenshot

Comment: Hi @Hoenie, I have posted my code.